# Recording a keyboard macro with actual character strings

Tags: keyboard-macros

I could not better word the question.

So, I have finalized a few `M-x` commands I want to execute on a buffer. I have also tried and tested a few regexps using `C-M-%` for search and replace.

Now, I want to put it all together. So, I `C-x (` and run those `M-x` commands and do those substitutions by `C-M-%`. In both the cases, I select the command and search/replace strings using up and down arrows to choose the appropriate one.

When I name and save the macro, I find that it has recorded those up and down arrows after `M-x` and `C-M-%`! How do I get the actual commands and search/  replace strings?

Comment: Type the strings as input, instead of using arrows to navigate to them.

Comment: @Drew the searches are fairly complex. I'm sure, I'll end up making some mistake. Is not there any other way?